# How do I draw a border to the right of every cell which is in the Nth column?

Tags: formatting, conditional-statements, libreoffice-calc, modular-arithmetic

For example, if n=4, I want to draw a border after every fourth column. So it looks like this if n=4 (and this is for all the columns):

[image: SO49163245 Q example]

I tried conditional formatting but it draws the border to the right of that cell, and not for the entire column.

Comment: What is the formula you tried?  If it works for the first row, then simply apply it to a larger range.  *Formula -> Conditional Formatting -> Manage* and modify the *Cell Range*.

Comment: maybe it's too easy, but can't you put a border to col D, and copy the col? When you're getting started, just paste as-is; when you already have data: paste formats?

Answer (score 2):

Select all cells and apply Conditional Formatting with a Formula is such as:

```
MOD(COLUMN(),4)=0
```

and a Cell Style with Borders similar to:

[image: SO49163245 example]